# In MVC, how can I retrieve records from database matching a range of string serial numbers that include numbers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I have an MVC application that uses Code First Entity Framework.

I have records in my database for serial numbers that are strings, and a combination of letters and numbers. **The last 4 are always the number part**.

I am trying to retrieve all records in between range A and B, so for example from **SERIAL-NO-0020** to **SERIAL-NO-0050**

I cannot convert the string number part to an integer because Linq To Entities doesn't support it. So as an example to get all records with a serial number higher than 20, this doesn't work:

```
var records = context.SerialNumbers.Where(m => Convert.ToDecimal(m.SerialNo.Substring(10, 4)) > 20).ToList();
```

Is there a way to do this without first pulling all the records from the database and filtering further?

Comment: Do you have rights to change the database?

Comment: If required, yes.

Comment: You need to create a computedd column like I do in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToDecimal` can't be translated to SQL when using it with Linq to Entities.

You can create a stored procedure that query the data so you can do anyahting that can't be done by EF.

Another solution is to create a computed column.

**First**, add a new property. Let name it `SerialId` in your `SerialNumber` entity.

**Second**, Decorate that property with a data annotation:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

or use fluent configuration if you want:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SerialNumber>().Property(t => t.SerialId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

**Third**, Add new EF migration and in the generated migration file, just update it by passing a new value to `defaultValueSql` parameter liek below:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn(
       "dbo.SerialNumber", 
       "SerialId", 
       c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CAST(SUBSTRING(SerialNo, 11, 4) AS INT)"));
}
```

The modification says that each line of `SerialNumber` table has a generated column and its value is calculated by using this SQL statement => `CAST(SUBSTRING(SerialNo, 11, 4) AS INT)`

You can update your database by running ef command => `update-databse`.

**Finally**, you can change your Linq to Entities like below and you don't need any conversion:

```
var records = context.SerialNumbers.Where(m => m.SerialId > 20).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Writing Queries you can write SP and access this SP (Stored Proceure) with the help of Linq.
In SP you can split the record first and then compare. It will also take less time and increase the performance.